# Using GWT with local database

Tags: database, gwt

As far as I know, there are two ways to create a local database on the browser, either go with HTML5 window.openDatabase or Google Gears.

Which one is better, and why?
Are there any other alternatives beside those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gears is deprecated whilst HTML5 WebStorage is rising.  Pick your poison.

Build yourself a "wrapper" around both and switch at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Gears is officially deprecated due to the HTML5 proposals. So unless you happen to have a large number of users who you know already have gears installed, go with the web storage as support will only get better as time goes on. Gears will stagnate at this point and is (for the time being) a dead end.